# login page --> popup change password dialog (Other method?)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going to implement login page with change password dialog popup. 
If user click the login link with username as get parameter in email, it will check in spring MVC function and popup change password dialog popup if need to change password.
Is there any other good method to do as I am concerning the security or hacking issue?

Comment: what is the concern with pop out? I dont see any concern as long as you encrypt it in hash instead of full password into db, by the way, your question only pure opinion which is not belong to this section

Comment: sorry, as my manager warned me about these issues.